# I am building a small off-grid solar power setup; I need help with the battery size and combination

Tags: batteries, solar-energy

I have four 12 V large tubular deep-cycle lead-acid batteries and I want to know which one of these is a better set-up and why:

1. combine two batteries to make one 24 V battery; this way I will have two 24 V batteries
2. combine all four batteries to make one 48 V battery

The load for this set-up is a normal household load and my inverter can work with either combination.

I think it's a question of power vs capacity and I want more capacity and long life for the batteries if possible.

Comment: think about the amount of current flowing in the wires for each battery configuration ... then think about the effect that wire resistance has on the voltage at the inverter input terminals for each battery configuration

Comment: Since these are already series cells (lead acid is about 2 V per cell), the main trade-off is about the copper costs. And this has little to do with power, if you size the copper correctly. You can go either way. However, you will require more copper at the lower voltage. So the copper may be cheaper at 48 V. If you were serious about capacity and long life, you'd use 2 V cells and charge them and manage them independently, but combine them in series as benefits you in copper wire costs. This is very much more difficult to achieve in practice. But it optimizes results.

Comment: if your inverter takes 48v, that's going to be the best option in terms of least waste and gentlest on the cells.

Comment: Note that point 1 is interesting when you have to carry out a battery modification or maintenance (change of a group of batteries) because the inverter can continue to operate at "half speed". But the restart must be well thought out ... first, check the voltages, identical (!!!) before paralleling ...

Comment: Not that it would change the answer, but merely out of curiosity, does "...12V, large, tubular, deep-cycle..." mean a battery like this? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00075OSCO/

Comment: @SolomonSlow If it is those Amazon batteries (which seems plausible) then the OP should read the data sheet if they haven't already done so. https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/C1dW4i48w7S.pdf. Quite a bit of useful information and precautions.

Comment: Won't make a major difference either way. 48V : lower copper losses. But a 24V system (2S2P) will work on either chain (2S1P). If you have to service one of the batteries, remove both batteries from that chain.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's a question of power vs capacity and

No difference.

The power delivered by each battery is 1/4 of the power taken by the load,  no matter how the batteries are connected.

> I want more capacity and long life for the batteries if possible.

No difference.

The energy contained in the 4 batteries is the same, no matter how the batteries are connected.

Comment: Hint: The power-lines in your neck of the woods. What's the ballpark figure for their voltage? Is it lower than, the same as or higher than the voltage of a wall-socket?

Next, batteries. Does their lifespan vary as a function of maximum discharge current? Does their capacity vary as a function of their service-life? What could this imply for the system?


Lifespan and capacity of the batteries were each clearly mentioned as parameters to optimize. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferable to connect lead-acid batteries in series, rather than in parallel.

Lead-acid batteries balance better when they are all charged with equal current, rather than all charged with equal voltage.

When the charging is balanced, the battery lasts longer. When the charging is unbalanced, one battery fails sooner than the other batteries.

The reason for using a 12V system instead of a 48V system is that people traditionally/historically had 12V lighting and load systems they wanted to connect to. But commercial systems always used 24V or 48V systems, because they lasted longer and took less money to maintain.

A 48V series connection will still become unbalanced in use, and should be overcharged ('equalization') to bring the low batteries back up to fully charged. This will overcharge the batteries that are already full, which will lead to water loss: part of battery maintenance is checking the fluid level.

Gel batteries can't be overcharged as hard, so you may not be able to do real equalization by boosting the series voltage. The only way to equalize might be to take the low battery out of the series and put it on a low voltage charger. If the batteries are all in parallel, you would just take the good batteries out of circuit, and run the charge current into the low battery, which is much easier.

Of course, the same applies to individual cells in a gel battery: it is harder to keep them equalized.  Which is a reason why commercial systems traditionally used individual flooded cells in series: you could check the levels and top them up.

Anyway: if you want to get the best value out of your batteries, connect them in series, keep them charged as much as possible, and check them regularly.